# How to change a picture dynamically when a button is pressed and save the state of that image

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Good morning people.

I have a problem where I need to change an image of an `imageView` when the `Button` is pressed and when it is pressed again change to the image that was previously. I even managed to do this through the `setBackgroundResource`, the problem is when I close the application or exit that particular `Activity` and return to it the image is back to the one that was in `android: background` from the beginning.

Can someone help me?

P.S. I'm using the translator, sorry if I have something spelled wrong.

**Xml code**

```xml
<Button
android:id="@+id/buttonLigarDesligar"
android:padding="10dp"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:background="@drawable/icone_ligar"/>

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imgStatus"
android:padding="10dp"
android:background="@drawable/icone_vermelho"
android:layout_width="40dp"
android:layout_height="40dp"/>
```

**Java code**

```
buttonLigarDesligar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int status = 0;

        if (status == 0){ 
            imgStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_on);
            status = 1;
        }else{
            imgStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icone_vermelho);
            status = 0;                   
        }
    }
});
```

}

Comment: save your status variable on a Shared Preferences, then when the app starts, check out the value from there. The app cannot handle the current state by itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing it this way. You need to save the state yourself.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

String status = preferences.getInt("status", 0);
```

In your onClicklistener

```
if (status == 0){ 
        imgStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_on);
        editor.putInt("status", 1);
    }else{
        imgStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icone_vermelho);
        editor.putInt("status", 0);            
    }
   editor.apply();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot. I was able to solve!